# DrRacket/Scheme circle undefined

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm a beginner learning Scheme. I tried to follow the [quick introduction](https://docs.racket-lang.org/quick/) to get familiar with the syntax, but stuck in step 3. When I type (circle 10), it gives me "circle: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition" Do I miss some library or I have to define circle first?

[output error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVPtR.png)

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `racket` language, but Racket is actually an ecosystem of many programming languages. The Quick tutorial uses the `slideshow` language, a variant of Racket designed for creating pictorial programs and slideshows. As mentioned in [section 2 of the tutorial](https://docs.racket-lang.org/quick/#%28part._.Set___%29), change the first line of your program to this:

```
#lang slideshow
```

…click Run, and `circle` should now be defined.

Comment: OOOOOO, I see!!! I switched the computer but forget to look back to step 2...i'm dumb-,-